# how to format string to hh:mm:ss?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a digital clock in C#. I have 3 counter objects for hours, minutes and seconds. It has to be in format `hh:mm:ss`.

What I managed to do

```
String hours =  _hours.Value.ToString();
String minutes = _minutes.Value.ToString();
String seconds = _seconds.Value.ToString();

if (hours.Length == 1)
{
    hours = "0" + hours;
}

if (minutes.Length == 1)
{
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
}

if (seconds.Length == 1)
{
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
}

return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
```

It works but I am trying for a more efficient way of doing it using String.format. I have tried few different regular expressions but have been unsuccessful.

```
string b = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:00}:{2:d2}", hours, minutes, seconds);
```

Cheers

Comment: What is the type of `_hours`, `_minutes`, and `_seconds`?

Comment: the are an object class. i have made a counter.

Comment: Why do you have "three counter objects" ? You shouldn't. DateTime has all you need. Just update your view in interval you like with the current DateTime ...

Comment: its a school project. Just learning how to use object class. its working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried converting the string into int, before trying your `string.Format`? Something like below

```
string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", 
                int.Parse(hours), int.Parse(minutes), int.Parse(seconds));
```

If `_hours.Value`, `_minutes.Value` and `_seconds.Value` are numeric types, then you can use the below code which is more efficient

```
string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", 
                _hours.Value, _minutes.Value, _seconds.Value);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can always try something a bit different:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, hours, minutes, seconds); // just ignore year, month and day
var x = dt.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 2):

IMO if you already have a `string` type it's useless to cast it to `int` or `DateTime` just to stringify it again after that.

I would use [`String.PadLeft`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx) method :

```
string h = hours.PadLeft(2, '0');
string m = minutes.PadLeft(2, '0');
string s = seconds.PadLeft(2, '0');
string result = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
```

`PadLeft` will make your string to always have length at least of the value passed as a first parameter ( `2` in this case ) and fill "empty" places with the value passed in second parameter ( `0` in this case ).

---

[Check this online](http://rextester.com/WHY80266)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the formatting options available on the `ToString()` method of `DateTime` like below:

```
 (new DateTime(1900, 1, 1, _hours.Value, _minutes.Value, _seconds.Value)).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using:

```
string b = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have some date variable, you can do so:

```
string b = dateVar.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

If you want solution exactly for your example, then:

```
return string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", 
    int.Parse(hours), 
    int.Parse(minutes), 
    int.Parse(seconds)
);
```